# Collect reaction from dm message triggered by 'guildMemberAdd'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

My bot sends a message when a new member is added to the guild. The message goes to a specific user.

```
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const adminDm = client.users.cache.get(Config.get('ADMIN'));
    client.commands.get('novoMembro').execute(member, adminDm);
});
```

Now I need to collect the reaction in order to assign some role to the new member.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'novoMembro',
    description: "Adding a new member to the guild",
    execute(member, adminDm){
        const novoMembroEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor([153,0,76])
        .setTitle('NOVO MEMBRO ADICIONADO')
        .setDescription(`<@!${member.id}> foi adicionado`)
        .addFields( 
            {name: 'Selecione uma opção:', value: 'Reaja com  para enviar mensagem de boas vindas \n Reaja com ❌ para cancelar'},
        );

        adminDm.send({ embeds: [novoMembroEmbed] }).then((msg => {
            msg.react('❌');
            msg.react('');
        }));
        
       
    }
}
```

Until this point, the code works fine. But I can't find a way to collect the reactions, every code I've tried doesn't work. I think I didn't understand right the concept of collecting reactions.
these are some code I've tried.

```
const filter = (reaction) => ['❌', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
const reactOptions = {maxEmojis: 1};

.then(() => msg.awaitReactions(filter, reactOptions)).then(collected => {
                if (collected.first().emoji.name === '') {
                    console.log('msg de boas vindas');
                }else{
                    console.log('cancelando');
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors with your code. In discord.js v13 the [`awaitReactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) and [`createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) accepts a single parameter and the `filter` is part of the `options` object now. (See [Changes in v13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#collectors).) So, you need to update that; pass down a single object with a `filter` and a `max` or `maxEmojis` key.

You'll also need to update your `filter` as it currently collects the bot's reactions too. By checking if the user who reacted is the same as the admin, you can make sure you only collect the reactions you need.

You could also make `execute` async and use the `await` keyword to wait for the promises to be resolved.

And one last thing; make sure you enabled the required intents: `DIRECT_MESSAGES` and `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`.

Check out the code below:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'novoMembro',
  description: 'Adding a new member to the guild',
  async execute(member, admin) {
    const novoMembroEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor([153, 0, 76])
      .setTitle('NOVO MEMBRO ADICIONADO')
      .setDescription(`<@!${member.id}> foi adicionado`)
      .addFields({
        name: 'Selecione uma opção:',
        value:
          'Reaja com  para enviar mensagem de boas vindas \n Reaja com ❌ para cancelar',
      });

    try {
      const sentDM = await admin.send({ embeds: [novoMembroEmbed] });
      // make sure you don't collect the bot's reactions
      const filter = (reaction, user) =>
        ['❌', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === admin.id;

      sentDM.react('❌');
      sentDM.react('');

      // add a single options object only
      const collected = await sentDM.awaitReactions({ filter, maxEmojis: 1 });

      if (collected.first().emoji.name === '') {
        admin.send('msg de boas vindas');
      } else {
        admin.send('cancelando');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It was missing Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS too.
Now it's 100%